# Odoo 8 - Howto add product.template many2one attribute name to product.product name_get

Tags: odoo-8

Hi I found several answers for only changing the name_get in one model, but not with a product.template many2one attribute in product.product name_get def...

Tried this:

```
def name_get(self, cr, user, ids, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    if isinstance(ids, (int, long)):
        ids = [ids]
    if not len(ids):
        return []

    def _name_get(d):
        name = d.get('name','')
        code = context.get('display_default_code', True) and d.get('default_code',False) or False
        attribute_id = product.product_tmpl_id.attribute_id
        if code:
            name = '[%s] %s - %s' % (code,attribute,name)
        return (d['id'], name)
```

this works well, but only returns the id of the attribute, not the name of it...

EDIT: 
This is about the module https://github.com/OCA/product-attribute/tree/8.0/product_brand
I want to add the brand name to the product name function to have this in POS and Purchase Order Form f.ex. ...

"[default_code] Brand name - Product name"

Comment: What is your requirement at view part and value? Id is only showing in drop-down? Not able to find out exactly what are you looking for?

Comment: watch my edit. should clarify things ;)

Answer (score 1):

this is how it works

```
def name_get(self, cr, user, ids, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    if isinstance(ids, (int, long)):
        ids = [ids]
    if not len(ids):
        return []

    def _name_get(d):
        name = d.get('name','')
        brand = product.product_tmpl_id.product_brand_id.name
        code = context.get('display_default_code', True) and d.get('default_code',False) or False
        if brand:
            name = '%s - %s' % (brand,name)
        if code:
            name = '[%s] - %s' % (code,name)
        return (d['id'], name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
def name_get(self, cr, user, ids, context=None):
    res = []
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    if isinstance(ids, (int, long)):
        ids = [ids]
    if not len(ids):
        return []

    for r in self.browse(cr, user, ids, context=context):
        name = r.name
        code = r.default_code
        attr_name = r.product_tmpl_id.product_brand_id and r.product_tmpl_id.product_brand_id.name or ''
        value = '[%s] %s - %s' % (code,attr_name,name) 
        res.append((r.id, name))
    return res
```

Comment: See I have updated answer and only adjusted indentation which you can also did my friend, it show you that something in code which is not properly  managed aligned which is must in python. so please just take the logic from the answer, so not paste the entire thing if possible.

Comment: I missed one thing in code, so I changes res.append statement.

Comment: updated the post with working edtition... yours should work too!